# C++ | Помогите понять побитовые операторы

Tags: битовые-операции

Есть такой код:

```
#define TEST (1<<0)
a &= ~TEST
```

Он равносилен этому?

```
a = a & (0<<1)
```

Или как?

Comment: Первый код сбрасывает младший бит, второй — сбрасывает все.

Comment: Операция `0 << n`  не имеет смысла, для любого `n` ее результатом будет 0. Если вы хотите установить в 0 n-ый бит в переменной `a`, то нужнo выполнить  операцию `&` (это вы правильно пишете) с числом, у которого все биты кроме n-го равны 1, а n-ый бит ноль. Именно таков смысл выражения `~(1 << n)` (операция `~` меняет значение всех бит числа на обратное)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define TEST (1<<0)
a &= ~TEST
```

Разбираем...

```
a = a & ~TEST
```

Но: `TEST` - это просто сдвиг единичного бита на 0 разрядов, или просто 1.

```
a = a & ~1
```

т.е.

```
a = a & 11...1110
```

Второй же оператор -

```
a = a & (0<<1)
```

В нем `0 << 1` - это сдвиг 0 на 1 разряд влево, т.е. просто 0:

```
a = a & 0
```

Или просто

```
a = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Побитовые операторы работают с двоичным представлением числа.

Обычное И && это результат конъюнкции двух логических выражений.

Побитовое И & это применение логической операции «поразрядно» к соответствующим битам числа.

Пример. x = 52, y = 21, 52 = 110100, 21 = 10101, 52 & 21 = 20

```
1 1 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1
-----------
0 1 0 1 0 0
```

Операторы побитового сдвига:

n<<1 эквивалентно умножению на 2. Все биты сдвигаются на 1 позицию влево, крайний левый бит отбрасывается.  Крайний правый заменяется на 0.

n>>1 эквивалентно целой части от деления на 2. Все биты сдвигаются на 1 позицию вправо, крайний правый бит отбрасывается. Крайний левый заменяется на 0.

```
a &= ~TEST
```

равносильно

```
a = a & (TEST)
a = a & ~(1<<0)
```